# Wrap a svg figure with text?

Tags: wrap, svg

I searched on the Internet but I couldn't find an answer. To have figures with more quality, I uploaded a few svg files into my LaTeX project. However, it seems to be **impossible to wrap a figure, which is using \includesvg** with package{svg}.

For illustration, if I write this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Title}
\centering \includesvg[width=0.73\textwidth]{...)/File.svg}\\
  \footnotesize{\textbf{Caption.}}
      \label{fig:svgfile}
\end{figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

That's broken and I can't do anything to adjust the text width (I mean nothing happens if I change the values).

[image]

Is it just because I'm a noob or because of something else? It's a little confusing and annoying because I used some svg files to have more quality but I can't add some text around it.

Comment: remove `\begin{figure}[H]` you should never have a `figure`  inside a wrapfig (or any other box)

Comment: You don't need to use a figure environment inside a wrapfigure environment.

Comment: wrapping text around a wrapfig is independent of its content. But you have not provided an example that can be used to see the issue

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wow, thank you a lot! I didn't know it would be so simple. I really feel like a noob ahah.

Comment: @ManuelMerino You're right! I deleted the figure environment and everything works well. Thank you!